# http 503 error gwt jetty server SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, jetty

i get 503 error from eclipse integrated jetty server while running project in a web browser. i get this error since i changed the gae application-id of the project.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:176)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:191)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:239)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:146)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
    21.08.2012 16:09:42 com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
    SCHWERWIEGEND: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
    javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerS ervice.java:191)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:239)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:146)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)

    21.08.2012 16:09:42 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
    WARNUNG: failed SystemServiceServlet: java.lang.NullPointerException
    21.08.2012 16:09:43 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
    WARNUNG: Failed startup of context    com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@9f4160a{/,C:\Users\dp\work        space\fooApp\war}
    java.lang.NullPointerException
     at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:191)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:239)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:146)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1068)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:811)
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
    21.08.2012 16:09:46 com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
    INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
    21.08.2012 16:09:46 com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
    INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
```

this is my web.xml file

```
<!-- Default page to serve -->
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>fooApp.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>phonegapfileapi</servlet-name>
   <servlet           class>com.googlecode.gwtphonegap.server.file.FileRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>phonegapfileapi</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/showcase/phonegapfileapi</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
       <init-param>
          <param-name>services</param-name>
       <param-value/>
     </init-param>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

all jars are in fooApp/war/WEB-INF/lib
how could i solve this problem?
please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this same problem. SystemServiceServlet seems to be needed only if you want to deploy the web admin servlet in jetty.

In my case the issue was the GAE eclipse plugin was using **GAE Java SDK 1.6** by default and the package com.google.api.server is no even there. I fixed it by setting the SDK manually to **GAE SDK 1.7**.

Be careful when changing the SDK, I tried by changing the default SDK but still had this problem until I selected "Use specific SDK" pointing to 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using maven, but had the same problem. With maven we don't have the SDK version set in project properties, instead we have this plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
```

**To solve the exception**:
`Window/Show View/Other... > Servers/Server` and then right click on the used AppEngine server then click `Clean...`.

*Note: this will wipe your local dev datastore*, so make a backup of the file if you want to keep your data:

> .../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp${SERVER_NUM}/${DEPLOYED_APP_NAME}/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin

Answer (score -1):

Solution in my situation - just kill all javaw.exe *32 process in task manager.