# What is causing an HTTP 503 error in my GWT application?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gwt, aopalliance

I followed this tutorial for my first project using [gwt,hibernate,jpa and spring](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/gwt-2-spring-3-jpa-2-hibernate-35-2.html).

However, when I try to right click on the app and use Run as -> web application in Eclipse, the page return:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503
---
Problem accessing /GWTSpring.html. Reason:
-
SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
-
Powered by Jetty://
```

-

This is what I got in the console:

```
Initializing App Engine server
Jun 03, 2013 4:37:20 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Innet\workspace\GWTSpring\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Jun 03, 2013 4:37:20 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Innet\workspace\GWTSpring\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Jun 03, 2013 4:37:20 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LoggingConfigurationManager loadPropertiesFile
WARNING: Unable to load properties file, C:\Users\Innet\workspace\GWTSpring\war\WEB-INF\logging.properties
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Innet\workspace\GWTSpring\war\WEB-INF\logging.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LoggingConfigurationManager.loadPropertiesFile(LoggingConfigurationManager.java:170)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LoggingConfigurationManager.read(LoggingConfigurationManager.java:78)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.validateAndRegisterGlobalValues(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:162)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.access$300(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:29)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager$WarServerConfigurationHandle.readConfiguration(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:400)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.<init>(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:137)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:83)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.<init>(DevAppServerImpl.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:165)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:69)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:53)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:84)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)

Jun 03, 2013 4:37:20 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Users\Innet\workspace\GWTSpring\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
Jun 03, 2013 4:37:20 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Jun 03, 2013 2:37:20 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
Jun 03, 2013 2:37:22 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
INFO: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Jun 03, 2013 2:37:25 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@5f3ad072{/,C:\Users\Innet\workspace\GWTSpring\war}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1403)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:408)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:230)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:307)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer.startup(AbstractServer.java:80)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Servers.startup(Servers.java:78)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:216)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$5.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1450)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1448)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.aop.Advice
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:214)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 38 more

Jun 03, 2013 2:37:25 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.aop.Advice
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:214)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$5.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1450)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1448)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:408)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:230)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:307)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer.startup(AbstractServer.java:80)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Servers.startup(Servers.java:78)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:216)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)

Jun 03, 2013 2:37:25 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
Jun 03, 2013 2:37:25 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
INFO: Server default is running at http://localhost:8888/
Jun 03, 2013 2:37:25 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
Jun 03, 2013 4:37:25 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
```

i've already tried this [solution: 503 GWT error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060233/http-503-error-gwt-jetty-server-service-unavailable): but it didn't work.

Any ideas as to what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.aop.Advice
```

is pretty much self explanatory, no? you need some "AOP Alliance" JAR in the CLASSPATH. Likely packaged with Spring downloads, or referenced from its pom.xml (if using Maven).

Answer (score 2):

in Project -> war -> lib -> web.xml

Delete -

```
<!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.proOne.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/projectone/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not obliged to use AppEngine, remove it! 
I have tried to use spring and Hibernate with GWT but it did not work with AppEngine.
The application server that will be used then, will be Jetty (the embedded server).
And remove all the jars related to AppEngine from your Build Path
It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to change ports in your project"s configuration.

> Right Click your project --> Run as..  -->  Run Configurations  --> Go
>   to Server tab and make it select an unused port.

I had the same problem but this worked for me like a charm.